# Error:SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, sql, database, pdo

In the following code what i'm trying to do is modify an archive, but the SQL error appears, is there something i'm missing?

```
    function modifica_imagen(){
    $datos=array(
        ':idimagen'=>$this->idimagen, 
        ':archivo'=>$this->archivo
        );
    if($this->nomimagen!=''){
        $archivo_temporal=$this->nomimagen;
        $this->recupera_imagen();
        $this->ruta_final='imagenes/'.$this->nomimagen;
        $this->borrar_archivo();
        $this->nomimagen=$archivo_temporal;
        $this->ruta_final=$archivo_temporal;
        $sql='nomimagen=:nomimagen';
        $datos[':nomimagen']=$this->nomimagen;
    }
    else{
        $sql='';
    }

    $conexion= new conexion();
    $consulta='UPDATE imagen SET archivo=:archivo'.$sql.'WHERE idimagen=:idimagen';
    $conexion->ejecutar_sentencia($consulta, $datos);
    $this->ruta_final='imagenes/'.$this->ruta_final;
    $this-> upload();
}
```

Comment: You are missing spaces before and after  `'.$sql.'`.

Comment: You also need a comma before `nomimagen=:nomimagen` for that to work, in addition to the spaces.

Comment: Aw yeah.. God, I'm such a blind.. Thanks to both... It worked

Comment: The problem would have been easy to see if you had printed out the SQL query in `$consulta`. It's easier to spot these errors quickly if you look at the final SQL, instead of all the PHP code that builds the SQL string.